# Remove leading column of zeros when executing a select statement to my MSSQL database

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, select

Hey guys i have microsoft sql management studio 18, where I have a database. I'm doing a select statement through php like this:

```
            $conn = OpenCon();
            
            $query = "SELECT id, name, picture, description, numberOfEngines FROM planes";
            $result = sqlsrv_query($conn, $query);
            
            if ($result === false) {
                $status['status'] = "0";
                echo json_encode($status);
            }
            else{
                while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result)) {
                    $theRows[] = $row;
                }
                echo json_encode($theRows);
            }
            CloseCon($conn);
```

and this is the output:

```
[{"0":1,"id":1,"1":"114","name":"114","2":"airplane1.png","picture":"airplane1.png","3":"Cessna C525","description":"Cessna C525","4":1,"numberOfEngines":1},
{"0":2,"id":2,"1":"115","name":"115","2":"airplane1.png","picture":"airplane1.png","3":"Cessna C525","description":"Cessna C525","4":1,"numberOfEngines":1},
{"0":3,"id":3,"1":"124","name":"124","2":"airplane1.png","picture":"airplane1.png","3":"Cessna C208B","description":"Cessna C208B","4":1,"numberOfEngines":1},
{"0":4,"id":4,"1":"125","name":"125","2":"airplane1.png","picture":"airplane1.png","3":"Cessna C208B","description":"Cessna C208B","4":1,"numberOfEngines":1}]
```

How can i remove that leading these duplicates that are showing up twice like the "0":1, or the ariplane.png.
So my output will be like this:

```
[{"id":1, "name":"114", "picture":"airplane1.png", "description":"Cessna C525", "numberOfEngines":1}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return only associative keys in your array, pass `SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC` as the `fetchType` parameter to [`sqlsrv_fetch_array`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-fetch-array):

```
while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($result, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
```

This will give you an array with entries like:

```
{"id":1,"name":"114","picture":"airplane1.png","description":"Cessna C525","numberOfEngines":1}
```

If you really want the other numeric keys, keep your code as is and add

```
unset($row[0])
```

before

```
$theRows[] = $row;
```

Comment: ok it worked thats perfect just one more thing, i need to make the ID come out as a string as well so {"id":"1"...

Comment: @Moe before you assign to `$theRows` you could use `$row['id'] = (string)$row['id'];`